# How can I build a unique tree structure from an XML file in VB.NET

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I have the need to create a unique list of nodes and attributes with counts from an XML file. Effectively I need a count of each node/attribute combination in a file of moderately unknown structure.

By way of example if I were to have an XML file which looks like;

```
<level1>
    <item id="a">blah</item>
    <item id="b">blah</item>
    <item id="c">blah</item>
    <level2>
        <item id="d">blah</item>
        <item id="e">blah</item>
        <item id="f">blah</item>
        <level3>
            <item id="g">blah</item>
            <item id="h">blah</item>
            <item id="i">blah</item>
            <item id="k">blah</item>
        </level3>
        <level3>
            <item id="g">blah</item>
            <item id="h">blah</item>
            <item id="i">blah</item>
            <item id="j">blah</item>
        </level3>
    </level2>
    <level2>
        <item id="d">blah</item>
        <item id="e">blah</item>
        <item id="f">blah</item>
        <item id="k">blah</item>
        <level3>
            <item id="g">blah</item>
            <item id="i">blah</item>
        </level3>
        <level3>
            <item id="g">blah</item>
            <item id="h">blah</item>
            <item id="j">blah</item>
        </level3>
    </level2>
<level1>
```

I might want something that looks like;

```
<level1 count="1">
    <item id="a">1</item>
    <item id="b">1</item>
    <item id="c">1</item>
    <level2 count="2">
        <item id="d">2</item>
        <item id="e">2</item>
        <item id="f">2</item>
        <item id="k">1</item>
        <level3 count="4">
            <item id="g">4</item>
            <item id="h">3</item>
            <item id="i">3</item>
            <item id="j">2</item>
            <item id="k">1</item>
        </level3>
    </level2>
<level1>
```

While I have expressed the output as an XML structure that was arbitrary. Really just needs a report of the information.

My development environment is VB.NET using VS2019. I have code which reads the XML tree but I need help designing the structure to store the data in, and the ability to search it to increment counters.

```
    For Each Element As XmlElement In XmlDoc.SelectNodes("//*")
        Console.WriteLine("Processing element with name {0}:", Element.Name)
        
        For Each Attribute As XmlAttribute In Element.Attributes

            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", Attribute.Name, Attribute.Value)

        Next

        Console.WriteLine()
    Next
```

Comment: You can recursively group and count elements easily in XQuery, XSLT (supported for the .NET framework by Saxon 10, for instance) or using LINQ to XML. Using DOM doesn't seem to be helpful for that task.

Comment: Do you know any examples of doing something similar to what I am interested in which you could link to?

Comment: Well, using grouping and recursion has been done here before but your requirements are not clear from that single sample. Do you want to count e.g. all `<item id="a">blah</item>` at all nesting levels? Or is that only if they are at the same depth?

Answer (score 1):

An example XSLT 3 stylesheet you can run with the .NET framework using Saxon 10 HE (or 9.9 or 9.8) is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="node()*">
    <xsl:param name="parents" as="node()*"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$parents/*" composite="yes" group-by="node-name(), @id">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:attribute name="count" select="count(current-group())"/>
          <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group())"/>
        </xsl:copy>      
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online sample is at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bESWQsP, output for your input (after closing the end tag of the root element) is e.g.

```
<level1 count="1">
   <item id="a" count="1"/>
   <item id="b" count="1"/>
   <item id="c" count="1"/>
   <level2 count="2">
      <item id="d" count="2"/>
      <item id="e" count="2"/>
      <item id="f" count="2"/>
      <level3 count="4">
         <item id="g" count="4"/>
         <item id="h" count="3"/>
         <item id="i" count="3"/>
         <item id="k" count="1"/>
         <item id="j" count="2"/>
      </level3>
      <item id="k" count="1"/>
   </level2>
</level1>
```

so I think it has the counts you are looking for.

The .NET API for Saxon 10 is documented at https://saxonica.com/html/documentation10/dotnetdoc/index.html with an introduction at https://saxonica.com/documentation10/index.html#!dotnet/dotnetapi so you basically use the `Processor` object to start with, create an `XsltCompiler` to compile above XSLT document to an `XsltExecutable` and then create an `Xslt30Transformer` from that to feed it the XML input you build first with a `DocumentBuilder` created from the `Processor` to the `ApplyTemplates` method or to the `Transform` method without using the `DocumentBuilder`, just with a `FileStream`.

So the shortest sample without any error handling (e.g. in the case the compilation or XSLT execution would give an error) is

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Saxon.Api

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim processor = New Processor()

        Dim xsltCompiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler()

        Dim xsltExecutable As XsltExecutable

        Using fs = File.OpenRead("recursive-grouping.xsl")
            xsltExecutable = xsltCompiler.Compile(fs)
        End Using

        Dim xslt30Processor = xsltExecutable.Load30()

        Using fs = File.OpenRead("input-sample.xml")
            xslt30Processor.Transform(fs, processor.NewSerializer(Console.Out))
        End Using
    End Sub

End Module
```

Online at https://github.com/martin-honnen/SaxonXSLT30ExampleWithVB.

Or use LINQ grouping with LINQ to XML, at least as long as you only need to group by the known id attribute:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim doc = <?xml version="1.0"?>
              <level1>
                  <item id="a">blah</item>
                  <item id="b">blah</item>
                  <item id="c">blah</item>
                  <level2>
                      <item id="d">blah</item>
                      <item id="e">blah</item>
                      <item id="f">blah</item>
                      <level3>
                          <item id="g">blah</item>
                          <item id="h">blah</item>
                          <item id="i">blah</item>
                          <item id="k">blah</item>
                      </level3>
                      <level3>
                          <item id="g">blah</item>
                          <item id="h">blah</item>
                          <item id="i">blah</item>
                          <item id="j">blah</item>
                      </level3>
                  </level2>
                  <level2>
                      <item id="d">blah</item>
                      <item id="e">blah</item>
                      <item id="f">blah</item>
                      <item id="k">blah</item>
                      <level3>
                          <item id="g">blah</item>
                          <item id="i">blah</item>
                      </level3>
                      <level3>
                          <item id="g">blah</item>
                          <item id="h">blah</item>
                          <item id="j">blah</item>
                      </level3>
                  </level2>
              </level1>

    Console.WriteLine(New XDocument(GroupChildren({doc})))

End Sub

Function GroupChildren(parents As IEnumerable(Of XContainer)) As IEnumerable(Of XContainer)
    Return From child In parents.Elements()
           Group By nameCount = New With {
             Key .Name = child.Name,
             Key .Id = child.@id
    } Into group = Group
           Select <<%= nameCount.Name %> Count=<%= group.Count() %> Id=<%= nameCount.Id %>>
                      <%= GroupChildren(group) %>
                  </>
End Function
```

Comment: I like the concept of the Saxon 10 stylesheet approach. I have started to look at the documentation. In order to jump start my understanding are there any code examples in VB.NET, C#?

Comment: The download page https://www.saxonica.com/download/download_page.xml#resources has a resources zip that contains C# sample (together with Java and XML, so look at the `cs` folder). Some of them are also online at https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/repository/he/revisions/master/entry/latest10/samples/cs/ExamplesHE.cs. I am afraid I don't know of any VB.NET samples but most "transcriptions" between C# and VB.NET are relatively easy, there might even be online converters.